# Is this asp compiled somehow?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx document (I know nothing about `asp`, `.net`, `aspx`, nada). It is a normal html table structure for the most part, but there are strings of asp that seem to be inserting some sort of dynamic content. They are in the form:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgTopImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/topbar.jpg" />    
<asp:Label ID="lblStyleCaption" runat="server" CssClass="label_caption" Text="Theme: " Visible="false" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropStyles"  Width="150" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

It seems that whenever I delete one of these——something as innocuous as, say, the line with the `asp:Image` tag, which I would think should just remove the image, when I load the page I get run-time errors. It's very particular. My question is, is this compiled somehow, which is making it so fragile. Even just changing the `topbar.jpg` to `something.png` gives me an error. Do I need to track down the original files this was compiled from, or is this normal server-side asp(x?) that I'm just somehow else goofing up my changes to?

Comment: aspx pages are compiled, yes.

Comment: I don't believe changing the `ImageUrl` should ever give an error, but it might if the url cannot be resolved (i.e. the image doesn't exist).

Comment: @Shmiddty Are they *necessarily* compiled. Or sometimes not? Does this  characteristic (compilation) make them impossible to edit post-compilation? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that depends on how the application is configured. I'm sure you could find a better answer if you googled it.

Comment: A quick search suggests that "Web Application Projects" will require a recompilation in visual studio whereas a "Web Project" will recompile on the fly. But I'm not completely certain on the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASPX pages are compiled, and those tags refer to objects that are known to the server, so removing them could cause errors.

**First, some basics in layman's terms**

Tags that begin with ASP:  (Example, `<ASP:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="Server" Text="Click Me" />`)

are not standard html buttons.  They are ***server controls***.  When generating the html that goes out to the browser, the ASP.NET runtime looks at the server controls and creates the appropriate content depending on the browser visiting the page.

In the case of the Button control, it's usually a standard html button, but the runtime also generates the  JavaScript and such to handle the button's server-side click event.

**Why you're probably seeing errors when you remove a control:**

Quite often, there's server-side code that's written that accesses these controls.  For example, the developer may have decided to change the Text or the Visible property due to some event.

If this is the case, and you remove the `<asp:Button>` tag, then there will be server-side code that references an object that no longer exists in the aspx page, hence the errors.

More at these links on Server Controls:

- http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_controls.asp
- (Actually, this older one is better for a new-to-asp.net developer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1(VS.71).aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306459

I'd also recommend taking some time watching basic videos or going through the tutorials at http://www.asp.net/get-started

---

I just noticed this in your question:

> Even just changing the topbar.jpg to something.png gives me an error.

That is a bit odd, but I know of at least one way it could happen...

Generally, Visual Studio will give you a ***warning*** (and not an error) if you include a relative URL to an image or a linked page that doesn't exist.  The warning shouldn't block you from compiling.  However, Visual Studio does have a setting that tells it to treat warnings as errors.  That will block it from compiling.  Here's how that would be set up:

> from Project Settings> Configuration Properties select the build
>   setting and change the “treat warnings as errors” settings to true.

If you wish to NOT treat warnings as errors, simply change the setting to false.

Comment: Thanks, David. This seems a bit opaque to me, but thanks for helping me get started learning! :)

Comment: Yeah, a full explanation of server controls is a bit big for the scope of the site.  I edited in that second link explaining Server Controls - it's WAY better than the first.  I'd start there if I were you.  It's too bad, but there used to be an awesome site for learning ASP.NET when it was new, but it's been replaced.  I wish it were still around.